# JSlider fitting the width of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Is there any way to make a `JSlider` to fit the width of a `JPanel` when it resizes? I'm now using. `JFrame`'s `pack()` method and when I resize the panel in which the slider is contained, the slider doesn't change its size.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual sizing behaviour is controlled by the LayoutManager used in the panel. The default is FlowLayout which keeps the children at their preferredSize. Change to a LayoutManager which sizes them bigger/smaller than their pref, for a single child f.i. the center of a BorderLayout:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 panel.add(mySlider)
```

There are others, read the [chapter about LayoutManagers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) in snoracle's [online Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)